# Crystal Reports - Grouping records

Tags: crystal-reports, report, grouping

I'm trying to group records based on an age range formula where the ranges overlap and it's possible a person will belong to more than one range, my formula looks as follows

```
   if {@Age} in 55 to 75 then
       "55-75" else
   if {@Age} in 40 to 75 then
       "40-75" else 
   if {@Age} in 18 to 75 then
       "18-75"
```

My problem is I can't get the people to show up in multiple groups if they belong to more than one.

Comment: Are you just looking to summarize the data as totals, etc.? You won't be able to actually group the records the way you want; A record can only fall into one group, otherwise it would require that one formula evaluate to multiple values for the same record which wouldn't make sense.

Answer (score 2):

Simple answer: what you are trying to do won't work.  Crystal Reports will place the record in one and only one group.

If you just need to tally values, I would suggest the following:

```
//{@bucket 01}
if {@Age} in 55 to 75 then
  1
else
  0

//{@bucket 02}
if {@Age} in 40 to 75 then
  1
else
  0

//{@bucket 03}
if {@Age} in 18 to 75 then
  1
else
  0
```

If you really need to group by age range, you will need to switch to a Command (instead of using the visual-linking 'expert'), then create a UNION query that creates recordsets for each bucket.